# XSLT replace \n with </p><p>

Tags: xml, xslt, line-breaks

I have an XML that in one node has a bunch of text with several paragraphs. I need to replace the \n with `</p><p>` the text section in all will have a `<p>` at the start and a `</p>` at the end in the XSLT definition.

I have tried this but it gives me an error in Saxon: *Variable find_all has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)*

```
<xsl:template match="/csv/row/col[17]">
    <xsl:param name="find_all">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="find_return">
        <xsl:text>(.*)\n(.*)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="replace_return">
        <xsl:text>$1&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;$2</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>
</xsl:template>
```

And later this:

```
<col name="Model descr.">
    <content>
        <xsl:text>&lt;p&gt;</xsl:text>
    </content>
    <content>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace($find_all, $find_return, $replace_return)"/>
    </content>
    <content>
        <xsl:text>&lt;/p&gt;</xsl:text>
    </content>
</col>
```

Whats's wrong here??

Thanks

Jan

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the wrong approach here. For a start, from the snippets you have shown us, you have a template with parameters, but those parameters are local in scope to that template. If you are trying to use those parameters outside the template, they won't be accessible.

Additionally, the `replace` function works with strings, and you cannot use it to create new elements like `<p>`. What you will create in your output is the escaped value of `&lt;p&gt;`.

A different approach to take is use the `tokenize` function, to split the text based on the line-break, and iterate over each item, wrapping it in a new `<p>` tag.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="text()" priority="2">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\n')[normalize-space()]">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </p>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You may also need `<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` to avoid getting two levels of `p` tags if there are existing marked-up paragraphs.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work for me. The thing I'm working is for a system that receives XML, send it to a processor that create an HMTL and from the HTML outputs a PDF. Each node in my XML is for a variable in to a JavsScript that is combined with an HTML template that becomes a PDF.

So in the HTML template we already have a DIV and a P tag for this variable. My problem is when a long text contains line breaks. Since the starting paragraph tag already is in place I have to convert the linebreak to end P and then a new Start P, see the title of my post.

Answer (score 0):

OK looking some more in to this I will go a step further. My process involves an XSLT that splits the node `<row>` in to single XML files. It will be easier to run the tokenize function on this smaller XML file.

But I only want to tokenize the text in just on of the nodes of this XML, how do I select just that one. I found this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/excel-row/col">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\n')">
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() eq last())">
            <br />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The xml node looks like this:

```
<col name="Model descr.">Some text in first paragraph.
More text in second paragraph.
And then a third paragraph with more text.
```

Then we have the last paragraph.

So how do I select the node `col name="Model descr.">`

Thankful for any help, my XSLT experience is limited as you see.

Jan